# Plot a set of inequalities for branch and bound problems in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, branch-and-bound

I'm studying the behavior of the branch and bound algorithm in a integer 2-variable linear problem.
I occasionally use Wolfram Alpha for plotting graphs, but now I need a more robust option, Mathematica.
I need to plot the viable zone of a set of inequalities on the R2 space (with x and y greater than 0), inequalities such as:

2*x+4*y <= 12  //  6*x+2*y <= 27   // x <= 4  // x>=0 //  y>=0

The graph must show all integer x,y points on the positive quadrant (I think a mesh function can do this) and a specific point (solution of the max/minimization problem)
For example, the viable space in this case is:
[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%282*x%2B4*y%3C%3D12%2C6*x%2B2*y%3C%3D27%2Cx%3C%3D4%2Cx%3E%3D0%2Cy%3E%3D0%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%282%2ax%2b4%2ay%3C=12,6%2ax%2b2%2ay%3C=27,x%3C=4,x%3E=0,y%3E=0%29)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is not in a format suitable for the site. It is too general. Can you show what you have tried? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[
 2 x + 4 y <= 12 && 6 x + 2 y <= 27 && x <= 4 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {x,
   0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

To make a nice-looking plot over the integer points the inequality satisfies, here is a function to plot it:

```
IntegerRegionPlot[quantifier_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}] := 
  Graphics[Flatten[
    Table[If[
      quantifier, {Red, Disk[{x, y}, 0.5]}, {Blue, 
       Disk[{x, y}, 0.5]}], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]], 
   Frame -> True];
```

To plot the inequality, just do this:

```
IntegerRegionPlot[
 2 x + 4 y <= 12 && 6 x + 2 y <= 27 && x <= 4 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {0,
   5}, {0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: oh. thanks! And, what should I do to force all integer points and one specific point?!

Comment: @alfablac: Appended code to only show true-false values at integer points.

Comment: I did slighty different you said, using another question from here on SO, but your answer for the regionplot command was essential. thanks!